# Flutter SVG gradient is not rendered: Failed to find definition for url

Tags: flutter, dart, svg, flutter-layout

I have this gradient image

[image: Screenshot]

but it seems that [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) is not able to render it.

The code of the image is:

```
<svg width="249" height="76" viewBox="0 0 249 76" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M156.656 57.6692C153.048 57.6692 149.734 56.8297 146.714 55.1506C143.693 53.4715 141.26 51.1628 139.415 48.2244C137.653 45.202 136.772 41.8019 136.772 38.0239C136.772 34.162 137.653 30.8038 139.415 27.9494C141.26 25.011 143.693 22.7442 146.714 21.1491C149.734 19.47 153.048 18.6304 156.656 18.6304C160.347 18.6304 163.661 19.47 166.597 21.1491C169.618 22.7442 172.009 25.011 173.771 27.9494C175.533 30.8038 176.413 34.162 176.413 38.0239C176.413 41.8019 175.533 45.202 173.771 48.2244C172.009 51.1628 169.618 53.4715 166.597 55.1506C163.661 56.8297 160.347 57.6692 156.656 57.6692ZM156.656 47.4688C159.256 47.4688 161.354 46.5873 162.948 44.8242C164.626 42.9772 165.465 40.7104 165.465 38.0239C165.465 35.2534 164.626 33.0286 162.948 31.3495C161.354 29.6704 159.256 28.8309 156.656 28.8309C154.139 28.8309 151.999 29.6704 150.237 31.3495C148.559 33.0286 147.721 35.2534 147.721 38.0239C147.721 40.7104 148.559 42.9772 150.237 44.8242C151.999 46.5873 154.139 47.4688 156.656 47.4688Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear_809_1834)"/>
    <path d="M192.916 57.6692C187.211 57.6692 182.513 56.4939 178.822 54.1432C178.067 53.6394 177.521 53.0517 177.186 52.3801C176.85 51.6245 176.682 50.9109 176.682 50.2393C176.682 48.812 177.144 47.5108 178.067 46.3354C179.073 45.16 180.29 44.5723 181.716 44.5723C182.387 44.5723 183.058 44.7403 183.73 45.0761C185.24 45.7477 186.96 46.3354 188.889 46.8391C190.819 47.2589 192.581 47.4688 194.175 47.4688C197.279 47.4688 198.831 46.7552 198.831 45.3279C198.831 44.4884 198.454 43.7748 197.699 43.1871C196.943 42.5155 195.182 42.0537 192.413 41.8019C191.322 41.7179 189.896 41.55 188.134 41.2981C186.456 41.0463 184.778 40.5845 183.1 39.9129C181.422 39.1573 179.996 38.0659 178.822 36.6387C177.731 35.2114 177.186 33.2805 177.186 30.8458C177.186 27.0679 178.612 24.0875 181.464 21.9047C184.317 19.7218 188.134 18.6304 192.916 18.6304C195.685 18.6304 198.286 18.9243 200.719 19.512C203.236 20.0996 205.123 20.9812 206.382 22.1565C207.556 23.2479 208.144 24.5072 208.144 25.9345C208.144 27.1938 207.682 28.3272 206.759 29.3346C205.837 30.3421 204.662 30.8458 203.236 30.8458C202.481 30.8458 201.768 30.6779 201.096 30.3421C200.09 29.6704 198.789 29.1667 197.195 28.8309C195.685 28.4951 194.133 28.3272 192.539 28.3272C189.351 28.3272 187.757 28.9988 187.757 30.3421C187.757 30.9298 188.05 31.4755 188.638 31.9792C189.309 32.399 190.777 32.7768 193.042 33.1126C194.468 33.2805 196.104 33.5323 197.95 33.8682C199.796 34.12 201.558 34.6237 203.236 35.3793C204.998 36.051 206.466 37.1844 207.64 38.7795C208.815 40.3746 209.402 42.5574 209.402 45.3279C209.402 49.1059 207.892 52.1282 204.872 54.395C201.851 56.5778 197.866 57.6692 192.916 57.6692Z" fill="url(#paint1_linear_809_1834)"/>
    <path d="M208.358 23.6677C208.358 21.9886 208.946 20.7293 210.12 19.8897C211.295 19.0502 212.637 18.6304 214.147 18.6304C215.322 18.6304 216.329 18.9662 217.168 19.6379C218.091 20.2256 218.72 21.0651 219.055 22.1565L226.858 41.1722C227.277 42.2636 227.865 42.8093 228.62 42.8093C229.375 42.8093 229.92 42.2636 230.256 41.1722L237.051 22.1565C237.471 20.9812 238.142 20.0996 239.065 19.512C240.072 18.9243 241.12 18.6304 242.211 18.6304C243.637 18.6304 244.938 19.0922 246.112 20.0157C247.371 20.9392 248 22.1565 248 23.6677C248 24.5072 247.832 25.3048 247.497 26.0604L227.865 71.3958C227.277 72.6551 226.522 73.5366 225.599 74.0404C224.76 74.628 223.879 74.9219 222.957 74.9219C221.446 74.9219 220.062 74.3762 218.804 73.2848C217.629 72.2773 217.042 71.06 217.042 69.6327C217.042 68.8772 217.21 68.2055 217.545 67.6178L224.341 55.5284C222.915 55.1086 221.782 54.0592 220.943 52.3801L208.736 25.9345C208.484 25.1789 208.358 24.4233 208.358 23.6677Z" fill="url(#paint2_linear_809_1834)"/>
    <path d="M45.0462 53.0098C43.4521 54.2691 41.0191 55.3605 37.7471 56.284C34.4751 57.2075 31.287 57.6692 28.1828 57.6692C22.9811 57.6692 18.3248 56.5359 14.2139 54.2691C10.1029 51.9184 6.87283 48.6861 4.5237 44.5723C2.17457 40.4586 1 35.7991 1 30.5939C1 25.1369 2.13262 20.4355 4.39785 16.4896C6.74698 12.5437 9.97703 9.52137 14.088 7.42251C18.199 5.2397 22.9811 4.14829 28.4345 4.14829C30.6997 4.14829 32.965 4.35818 35.2302 4.77795C37.5793 5.19772 39.7187 5.86936 41.6483 6.79286C42.6551 7.29658 43.3682 7.96822 43.7877 8.80776C44.2911 9.56335 44.5428 10.4029 44.5428 11.3264C44.5428 12.6697 44.0394 13.929 43.0327 15.1043C42.1098 16.1958 40.8513 16.7415 39.2573 16.7415C38.5861 16.7415 37.873 16.6155 37.1179 16.3637C35.6077 15.776 33.9717 15.3142 32.2099 14.9784C30.448 14.5586 28.8959 14.3488 27.5536 14.3488C23.1909 14.3488 19.5414 15.818 16.6049 18.7564C13.7524 21.6948 12.3262 25.6406 12.3262 30.5939C12.3262 35.8831 13.7944 40.0388 16.7308 43.0612C19.7511 46.0835 23.6104 47.5947 28.3086 47.5947C30.2383 47.5947 32.2938 47.2589 34.4751 46.5873C36.6564 45.9156 38.4183 45.0761 39.7607 44.0686C40.6835 43.4809 41.6903 43.1871 42.781 43.1871C44.2072 43.1871 45.3398 43.6908 46.1788 44.6983C47.1017 45.6218 47.5631 46.7971 47.5631 48.2244C47.5631 50.0714 46.7241 51.6665 45.0462 53.0098Z" fill="url(#paint3_linear_809_1834)"/>
    <path d="M56.587 57.6692C54.993 57.6692 53.6506 57.2075 52.5599 56.284C51.4693 55.3605 50.9239 54.1851 50.9239 52.7579V5.91133C50.9239 4.56806 51.4273 3.43468 52.4341 2.51118C53.5248 1.50373 54.9091 1 56.587 1C58.1811 1 59.4815 1.50373 60.4883 2.51118C61.495 3.43468 61.9984 4.61004 61.9984 6.03727V22.7862C63.0891 21.5269 64.5573 20.5194 66.403 19.7638C68.2488 19.0082 70.2204 18.6304 72.3178 18.6304C77.0161 18.6304 80.7915 20.0157 83.644 22.7862C86.5804 25.5567 88.0486 29.9643 88.0486 36.009V53.0098C88.0486 54.353 87.5033 55.4864 86.4126 56.4099C85.4058 57.2495 84.1054 57.6692 82.5114 57.6692C80.9173 57.6692 79.5749 57.2075 78.4843 56.284C77.4775 55.3605 76.9741 54.1851 76.9741 52.7579V37.3942C76.9741 34.2879 76.261 32.0631 74.8347 30.7199C73.4924 29.3766 71.8144 28.705 69.8009 28.705C67.7034 28.705 65.9835 29.4186 64.6412 30.8458C63.2988 32.1891 62.4179 33.7002 61.9984 35.3793V52.632C61.9984 54.0592 61.4531 55.2765 60.3624 56.284C59.3556 57.2075 58.0972 57.6692 56.587 57.6692Z" fill="url(#paint4_linear_809_1834)"/>
    <path d="M112.376 9.31541C105.287 10.0754 102.882 22.2992 102.565 28.3161C100.287 29.0761 100.139 22.2992 100.35 18.8158C100.35 17.5491 99.7172 17.0213 99.4007 16.9157C97.9239 16.7046 94.6537 18.1191 93.3879 25.466C92.122 32.813 93.2305 38.8017 93.7355 40.9747C93.9361 41.8379 94.5902 43.6632 95.1622 44.9008C96.8117 48.4699 99.3143 51.8243 103.198 54.6004C108.515 58.4006 116.806 58.0839 120.287 57.4505C123.874 56.6061 130.127 53.2449 132.313 46.6835C134.528 40.0332 133.79 36.5498 133.262 35.9164C132.946 35.0719 131.743 33.383 129.465 33.383C127.186 33.383 126.195 35.4942 125.984 36.5498C125.878 36.7609 125.667 37.8165 125.667 40.3499C125.667 42.8833 123.557 45.4168 122.503 46.3668C120.182 47.6335 114.654 49.2169 111.11 45.4168C107.565 41.6166 109.211 37.4998 110.477 35.9164C111.215 34.8608 113.515 32.6863 116.806 32.4329C120.097 32.1796 123.241 35.0719 124.401 36.5498C124.148 33.763 127.039 31.5885 128.515 30.8495C125.667 27.9994 122.819 26.7327 121.553 26.0994C120.54 25.5927 120.92 23.8826 121.553 23.2493L131.68 11.5322L125.351 17.5491L126.808 16.1639L131.68 11.5322C131.996 10.7932 131.49 9.44209 126.933 9.94877C121.237 10.5821 114.591 21.6659 111.426 23.2493C108.895 24.516 110.16 20.8214 111.11 18.8158C112.059 17.2324 114.085 13.5589 114.591 11.5322C115.097 9.50542 113.325 9.20986 112.376 9.31541Z" fill="url(#paint5_linear_809_1834)"/>
    <path d="M131.68 11.5322C131.996 10.7932 131.49 9.44209 126.933 9.94877C121.237 10.5821 114.591 21.6659 111.426 23.2493C108.895 24.516 110.16 20.8214 111.11 18.8158C112.059 17.2324 114.085 13.5589 114.591 11.5322C115.097 9.50542 113.325 9.20986 112.376 9.31541C105.287 10.0754 102.882 22.2992 102.565 28.3161C100.287 29.0761 100.139 22.2992 100.35 18.8158C100.35 17.5491 99.7172 17.0213 99.4007 16.9157C97.9239 16.7046 94.6537 18.1191 93.3879 25.466C92.122 32.813 93.2305 38.8017 93.7355 40.9747M131.68 11.5322L126.808 16.1639L125.351 17.5491L131.68 11.5322ZM131.68 11.5322L121.553 23.2493C120.92 23.8826 120.54 25.5927 121.553 26.0994C122.819 26.7327 125.667 27.9994 128.515 30.8495C127.039 31.5885 124.148 33.763 124.401 36.5498C123.241 35.0719 120.097 32.1796 116.806 32.4329C113.515 32.6863 111.215 34.8608 110.477 35.9164C109.211 37.4998 107.565 41.6166 111.11 45.4168C114.654 49.2169 120.182 47.6335 122.503 46.3668C123.557 45.4168 125.667 42.8833 125.667 40.3499C125.667 37.8165 125.878 36.7609 125.984 36.5498C126.195 35.4942 127.186 33.383 129.465 33.383C131.743 33.383 132.946 35.0719 133.262 35.9164C133.79 36.5498 134.528 40.0332 132.313 46.6835C130.127 53.2449 123.874 56.6061 120.287 57.4505C116.806 58.0839 108.515 58.4006 103.198 54.6004C99.3143 51.8243 96.8117 48.4699 95.1622 44.9008M93.7355 40.9747C93.9361 41.8379 94.5902 43.6632 95.1622 44.9008M93.7355 40.9747L95.1622 44.9008M156.656 57.6692C153.048 57.6692 149.734 56.8297 146.714 55.1506C143.693 53.4715 141.26 51.1628 139.415 48.2244C137.653 45.202 136.772 41.8019 136.772 38.0239C136.772 34.162 137.653 30.8038 139.415 27.9494C141.26 25.011 143.693 22.7442 146.714 21.1491C149.734 19.47 153.048 18.6304 156.656 18.6304C160.347 18.6304 163.661 19.47 166.597 21.1491C169.618 22.7442 172.009 25.011 173.771 27.9494C175.533 30.8038 176.413 34.162 176.413 38.0239C176.413 41.8019 175.533 45.202 173.771 48.2244C172.009 51.1628 169.618 53.4715 166.597 55.1506C163.661 56.8297 160.347 57.6692 156.656 57.6692ZM156.656 47.4688C159.256 47.4688 161.354 46.5873 162.948 44.8242C164.626 42.9772 165.465 40.7104 165.465 38.0239C165.465 35.2534 164.626 33.0286 162.948 31.3495C161.354 29.6704 159.256 28.8309 156.656 28.8309C154.139 28.8309 151.999 29.6704 150.237 31.3495C148.559 33.0286 147.721 35.2534 147.721 38.0239C147.721 40.7104 148.559 42.9772 150.237 44.8242C151.999 46.5873 154.139 47.4688 156.656 47.4688ZM192.916 57.6692C187.211 57.6692 182.513 56.4939 178.822 54.1431C178.067 53.6394 177.521 53.0517 177.186 52.3801C176.85 51.6245 176.682 50.9109 176.682 50.2393C176.682 48.812 177.144 47.5108 178.067 46.3354C179.073 45.16 180.29 44.5723 181.716 44.5723C182.387 44.5723 183.058 44.7403 183.73 45.0761C185.24 45.7477 186.96 46.3354 188.889 46.8391C190.819 47.2589 192.581 47.4688 194.175 47.4688C197.279 47.4688 198.831 46.7552 198.831 45.3279C198.831 44.4884 198.454 43.7748 197.699 43.1871C196.943 42.5155 195.182 42.0537 192.413 41.8019C191.322 41.7179 189.896 41.55 188.134 41.2981C186.456 41.0463 184.778 40.5845 183.1 39.9129C181.422 39.1573 179.996 38.0659 178.822 36.6387C177.731 35.2114 177.186 33.2805 177.186 30.8458C177.186 27.0679 178.612 24.0875 181.464 21.9047C184.317 19.7218 188.134 18.6304 192.916 18.6304C195.685 18.6304 198.286 18.9243 200.719 19.512C203.236 20.0996 205.123 20.9812 206.382 22.1565C207.556 23.2479 208.144 24.5072 208.144 25.9345C208.144 27.1938 207.682 28.3272 206.759 29.3346C205.837 30.3421 204.662 30.8458 203.236 30.8458C202.481 30.8458 201.768 30.6779 201.096 30.3421C200.09 29.6704 198.789 29.1667 197.195 28.8309C195.685 28.4951 194.133 28.3272 192.539 28.3272C189.351 28.3272 187.757 28.9988 187.757 30.3421C187.757 30.9298 188.05 31.4755 188.638 31.9792C189.309 32.399 190.777 32.7768 193.042 33.1126C194.468 33.2805 196.104 33.5323 197.95 33.8682C199.796 34.12 201.558 34.6237 203.236 35.3793C204.998 36.051 206.466 37.1844 207.64 38.7795C208.815 40.3746 209.402 42.5574 209.402 45.3279C209.402 49.1059 207.892 52.1282 204.872 54.395C201.851 56.5778 197.866 57.6692 192.916 57.6692ZM208.358 23.6677C208.358 21.9886 208.946 20.7293 210.12 19.8897C211.295 19.0502 212.637 18.6304 214.147 18.6304C215.322 18.6304 216.329 18.9662 217.168 19.6379C218.091 20.2256 218.72 21.0651 219.055 22.1565L226.858 41.1722C227.277 42.2636 227.865 42.8093 228.62 42.8093C229.375 42.8093 229.92 42.2636 230.256 41.1722L237.051 22.1565C237.471 20.9812 238.142 20.0996 239.065 19.512C240.072 18.9243 241.12 18.6304 242.211 18.6304C243.637 18.6304 244.938 19.0922 246.112 20.0157C247.371 20.9392 248 22.1565 248 23.6677C248 24.5072 247.832 25.3048 247.497 26.0604L227.865 71.3958C227.277 72.6551 226.522 73.5366 225.599 74.0403C224.76 74.628 223.879 74.9219 222.957 74.9219C221.446 74.9219 220.062 74.3762 218.804 73.2848C217.629 72.2773 217.042 71.06 217.042 69.6327C217.042 68.8772 217.21 68.2055 217.545 67.6178L224.341 55.5284C222.915 55.1086 221.782 54.0592 220.943 52.3801L208.736 25.9345C208.484 25.1789 208.358 24.4233 208.358 23.6677ZM45.0462 53.0098C43.4521 54.2691 41.0191 55.3605 37.7471 56.284C34.4751 57.2075 31.287 57.6692 28.1828 57.6692C22.9811 57.6692 18.3248 56.5359 14.2139 54.2691C10.1029 51.9184 6.87283 48.6861 4.5237 44.5723C2.17457 40.4586 1 35.7991 1 30.5939C1 25.1369 2.13262 20.4355 4.39785 16.4896C6.74698 12.5437 9.97703 9.52137 14.088 7.42251C18.199 5.2397 22.9811 4.14829 28.4345 4.14829C30.6997 4.14829 32.965 4.35818 35.2302 4.77795C37.5793 5.19772 39.7187 5.86936 41.6483 6.79286C42.6551 7.29658 43.3682 7.96822 43.7877 8.80776C44.2911 9.56335 44.5428 10.4029 44.5428 11.3264C44.5428 12.6697 44.0394 13.929 43.0327 15.1043C42.1098 16.1958 40.8513 16.7415 39.2573 16.7415C38.5861 16.7415 37.873 16.6155 37.1179 16.3637C35.6077 15.776 33.9717 15.3142 32.2099 14.9784C30.448 14.5586 28.8959 14.3488 27.5536 14.3488C23.1909 14.3488 19.5414 15.818 16.6049 18.7564C13.7524 21.6948 12.3262 25.6406 12.3262 30.5939C12.3262 35.8831 13.7944 40.0388 16.7308 43.0612C19.7511 46.0835 23.6104 47.5947 28.3086 47.5947C30.2383 47.5947 32.2938 47.2589 34.4751 46.5873C36.6564 45.9156 38.4183 45.0761 39.7607 44.0686C40.6835 43.4809 41.6903 43.1871 42.781 43.1871C44.2072 43.1871 45.3398 43.6908 46.1788 44.6983C47.1017 45.6218 47.5631 46.7971 47.5631 48.2244C47.5631 50.0714 46.7241 51.6665 45.0462 53.0098ZM56.587 57.6692C54.993 57.6692 53.6506 57.2075 52.5599 56.284C51.4693 55.3605 50.9239 54.1851 50.9239 52.7579V5.91133C50.9239 4.56806 51.4273 3.43468 52.4341 2.51118C53.5248 1.50373 54.9091 1 56.587 1C58.1811 1 59.4815 1.50373 60.4883 2.51118C61.495 3.43468 61.9984 4.61004 61.9984 6.03727V22.7862C63.0891 21.5269 64.5573 20.5194 66.403 19.7638C68.2488 19.0082 70.2204 18.6304 72.3178 18.6304C77.0161 18.6304 80.7915 20.0157 83.644 22.7862C86.5804 25.5567 88.0486 29.9643 88.0486 36.009V53.0098C88.0486 54.353 87.5033 55.4864 86.4126 56.4099C85.4058 57.2495 84.1054 57.6692 82.5114 57.6692C80.9173 57.6692 79.5749 57.2075 78.4843 56.284C77.4775 55.3605 76.9741 54.1851 76.9741 52.7579V37.3942C76.9741 34.2879 76.261 32.0631 74.8347 30.7199C73.4924 29.3766 71.8144 28.705 69.8009 28.705C67.7034 28.705 65.9835 29.4186 64.6412 30.8458C63.2988 32.1891 62.4179 33.7003 61.9984 35.3793V52.632C61.9984 54.0592 61.4531 55.2765 60.3624 56.284C59.3556 57.2075 58.0972 57.6692 56.587 57.6692Z" stroke="url(#paint6_linear_809_1834)" stroke-width="0.263406" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    <defs>
    <linearGradient id="paint0_linear_809_1834" x1="1" y1="74.5218" x2="120.071" y2="-92.6821" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop stop-color="#E96443"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#904E95"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="paint1_linear_809_1834" x1="1" y1="74.5218" x2="120.071" y2="-92.6821" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop stop-color="#E96443"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#904E95"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="paint2_linear_809_1834" x1="1" y1="74.5218" x2="120.071" y2="-92.6821" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop stop-color="#E96443"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#904E95"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="paint3_linear_809_1834" x1="1" y1="74.5218" x2="120.071" y2="-92.6821" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop stop-color="#E96443"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#904E95"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="paint4_linear_809_1834" x1="1" y1="74.5218" x2="120.071" y2="-92.6821" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop stop-color="#E96443"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#904E95"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="paint5_linear_809_1834" x1="1" y1="74.5218" x2="120.071" y2="-92.6821" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop stop-color="#E96443"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#904E95"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="paint6_linear_809_1834" x1="1" y1="74.5218" x2="120.071" y2="-92.6821" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop stop-color="#E96443"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#904E95"/>
    </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

I tried many things, but the SVG file should be correct. When in Flutter, I see the image in white.

The error I get is:

> **════════ Exception caught by SVG ═══════════════════════════════════════════════
> Failed to find definition for url(#paint6_linear_809_1834)**

It happens for all the paintN_linear points.

Comment: Can you include snippet how you are using this svg?

Comment: Share your error log, it should throw an error telling you if the SVG is properly formatted for flutter_svg to process it.

Comment: Try putting your SVG through this optimizer https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ it can recreate the structure of SVG to be more render-friendly. I used it many times when my SVG didn't render in a flutter.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just move the `defs` to the top, right below the `svg` tag.

Here's the result:

[image]

The XML is going to be like the following:

```xml
<svg width="249" height="76" viewBox="0 0 249 76" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <defs>
    <linearGradient id="paint0_linear_809_1834" x1="1" y1="74.5218" x2="120.071" y2="-92.6821" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop stop-color="#E96443"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#904E95"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="paint1_linear_809_1834" x1="1" y1="74.5218" x2="120.071" y2="-92.6821" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop stop-color="#E96443"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#904E95"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="paint2_linear_809_1834" x1="1" y1="74.5218" x2="120.071" y2="-92.6821" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop stop-color="#E96443"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#904E95"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="paint3_linear_809_1834" x1="1" y1="74.5218" x2="120.071" y2="-92.6821" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop stop-color="#E96443"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#904E95"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="paint4_linear_809_1834" x1="1" y1="74.5218" x2="120.071" y2="-92.6821" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop stop-color="#E96443"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#904E95"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="paint5_linear_809_1834" x1="1" y1="74.5218" x2="120.071" y2="-92.6821" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop stop-color="#E96443"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#904E95"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="paint6_linear_809_1834" x1="1" y1="74.5218" x2="120.071" y2="-92.6821" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop stop-color="#E96443"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#904E95"/>
    </linearGradient>
    </defs>

    <path d="M156.656 57.6692C153.048 57.6692 149.734 56.8297 146.714 55.1506C143.693 53.4715 141.26 51.1628 139.415 48.2244C137.653 45.202 136.772 41.8019 136.772 38.0239C136.772 34.162 137.653 30.8038 139.415 27.9494C141.26 25.011 143.693 22.7442 146.714 21.1491C149.734 19.47 153.048 18.6304 156.656 18.6304C160.347 18.6304 163.661 19.47 166.597 21.1491C169.618 22.7442 172.009 25.011 173.771 27.9494C175.533 30.8038 176.413 34.162 176.413 38.0239C176.413 41.8019 175.533 45.202 173.771 48.2244C172.009 51.1628 169.618 53.4715 166.597 55.1506C163.661 56.8297 160.347 57.6692 156.656 57.6692ZM156.656 47.4688C159.256 47.4688 161.354 46.5873 162.948 44.8242C164.626 42.9772 165.465 40.7104 165.465 38.0239C165.465 35.2534 164.626 33.0286 162.948 31.3495C161.354 29.6704 159.256 28.8309 156.656 28.8309C154.139 28.8309 151.999 29.6704 150.237 31.3495C148.559 33.0286 147.721 35.2534 147.721 38.0239C147.721 40.7104 148.559 42.9772 150.237 44.8242C151.999 46.5873 154.139 47.4688 156.656 47.4688Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear_809_1834)"/>
    <path d="M192.916 57.6692C187.211 57.6692 182.513 56.4939 178.822 54.1432C178.067 53.6394 177.521 53.0517 177.186 52.3801C176.85 51.6245 176.682 50.9109 176.682 50.2393C176.682 48.812 177.144 47.5108 178.067 46.3354C179.073 45.16 180.29 44.5723 181.716 44.5723C182.387 44.5723 183.058 44.7403 183.73 45.0761C185.24 45.7477 186.96 46.3354 188.889 46.8391C190.819 47.2589 192.581 47.4688 194.175 47.4688C197.279 47.4688 198.831 46.7552 198.831 45.3279C198.831 44.4884 198.454 43.7748 197.699 43.1871C196.943 42.5155 195.182 42.0537 192.413 41.8019C191.322 41.7179 189.896 41.55 188.134 41.2981C186.456 41.0463 184.778 40.5845 183.1 39.9129C181.422 39.1573 179.996 38.0659 178.822 36.6387C177.731 35.2114 177.186 33.2805 177.186 30.8458C177.186 27.0679 178.612 24.0875 181.464 21.9047C184.317 19.7218 188.134 18.6304 192.916 18.6304C195.685 18.6304 198.286 18.9243 200.719 19.512C203.236 20.0996 205.123 20.9812 206.382 22.1565C207.556 23.2479 208.144 24.5072 208.144 25.9345C208.144 27.1938 207.682 28.3272 206.759 29.3346C205.837 30.3421 204.662 30.8458 203.236 30.8458C202.481 30.8458 201.768 30.6779 201.096 30.3421C200.09 29.6704 198.789 29.1667 197.195 28.8309C195.685 28.4951 194.133 28.3272 192.539 28.3272C189.351 28.3272 187.757 28.9988 187.757 30.3421C187.757 30.9298 188.05 31.4755 188.638 31.9792C189.309 32.399 190.777 32.7768 193.042 33.1126C194.468 33.2805 196.104 33.5323 197.95 33.8682C199.796 34.12 201.558 34.6237 203.236 35.3793C204.998 36.051 206.466 37.1844 207.64 38.7795C208.815 40.3746 209.402 42.5574 209.402 45.3279C209.402 49.1059 207.892 52.1282 204.872 54.395C201.851 56.5778 197.866 57.6692 192.916 57.6692Z" fill="url(#paint1_linear_809_1834)"/>
    <path d="M208.358 23.6677C208.358 21.9886 208.946 20.7293 210.12 19.8897C211.295 19.0502 212.637 18.6304 214.147 18.6304C215.322 18.6304 216.329 18.9662 217.168 19.6379C218.091 20.2256 218.72 21.0651 219.055 22.1565L226.858 41.1722C227.277 42.2636 227.865 42.8093 228.62 42.8093C229.375 42.8093 229.92 42.2636 230.256 41.1722L237.051 22.1565C237.471 20.9812 238.142 20.0996 239.065 19.512C240.072 18.9243 241.12 18.6304 242.211 18.6304C243.637 18.6304 244.938 19.0922 246.112 20.0157C247.371 20.9392 248 22.1565 248 23.6677C248 24.5072 247.832 25.3048 247.497 26.0604L227.865 71.3958C227.277 72.6551 226.522 73.5366 225.599 74.0404C224.76 74.628 223.879 74.9219 222.957 74.9219C221.446 74.9219 220.062 74.3762 218.804 73.2848C217.629 72.2773 217.042 71.06 217.042 69.6327C217.042 68.8772 217.21 68.2055 217.545 67.6178L224.341 55.5284C222.915 55.1086 221.782 54.0592 220.943 52.3801L208.736 25.9345C208.484 25.1789 208.358 24.4233 208.358 23.6677Z" fill="url(#paint2_linear_809_1834)"/>
    <path d="M45.0462 53.0098C43.4521 54.2691 41.0191 55.3605 37.7471 56.284C34.4751 57.2075 31.287 57.6692 28.1828 57.6692C22.9811 57.6692 18.3248 56.5359 14.2139 54.2691C10.1029 51.9184 6.87283 48.6861 4.5237 44.5723C2.17457 40.4586 1 35.7991 1 30.5939C1 25.1369 2.13262 20.4355 4.39785 16.4896C6.74698 12.5437 9.97703 9.52137 14.088 7.42251C18.199 5.2397 22.9811 4.14829 28.4345 4.14829C30.6997 4.14829 32.965 4.35818 35.2302 4.77795C37.5793 5.19772 39.7187 5.86936 41.6483 6.79286C42.6551 7.29658 43.3682 7.96822 43.7877 8.80776C44.2911 9.56335 44.5428 10.4029 44.5428 11.3264C44.5428 12.6697 44.0394 13.929 43.0327 15.1043C42.1098 16.1958 40.8513 16.7415 39.2573 16.7415C38.5861 16.7415 37.873 16.6155 37.1179 16.3637C35.6077 15.776 33.9717 15.3142 32.2099 14.9784C30.448 14.5586 28.8959 14.3488 27.5536 14.3488C23.1909 14.3488 19.5414 15.818 16.6049 18.7564C13.7524 21.6948 12.3262 25.6406 12.3262 30.5939C12.3262 35.8831 13.7944 40.0388 16.7308 43.0612C19.7511 46.0835 23.6104 47.5947 28.3086 47.5947C30.2383 47.5947 32.2938 47.2589 34.4751 46.5873C36.6564 45.9156 38.4183 45.0761 39.7607 44.0686C40.6835 43.4809 41.6903 43.1871 42.781 43.1871C44.2072 43.1871 45.3398 43.6908 46.1788 44.6983C47.1017 45.6218 47.5631 46.7971 47.5631 48.2244C47.5631 50.0714 46.7241 51.6665 45.0462 53.0098Z" fill="url(#paint3_linear_809_1834)"/>
    <path d="M56.587 57.6692C54.993 57.6692 53.6506 57.2075 52.5599 56.284C51.4693 55.3605 50.9239 54.1851 50.9239 52.7579V5.91133C50.9239 4.56806 51.4273 3.43468 52.4341 2.51118C53.5248 1.50373 54.9091 1 56.587 1C58.1811 1 59.4815 1.50373 60.4883 2.51118C61.495 3.43468 61.9984 4.61004 61.9984 6.03727V22.7862C63.0891 21.5269 64.5573 20.5194 66.403 19.7638C68.2488 19.0082 70.2204 18.6304 72.3178 18.6304C77.0161 18.6304 80.7915 20.0157 83.644 22.7862C86.5804 25.5567 88.0486 29.9643 88.0486 36.009V53.0098C88.0486 54.353 87.5033 55.4864 86.4126 56.4099C85.4058 57.2495 84.1054 57.6692 82.5114 57.6692C80.9173 57.6692 79.5749 57.2075 78.4843 56.284C77.4775 55.3605 76.9741 54.1851 76.9741 52.7579V37.3942C76.9741 34.2879 76.261 32.0631 74.8347 30.7199C73.4924 29.3766 71.8144 28.705 69.8009 28.705C67.7034 28.705 65.9835 29.4186 64.6412 30.8458C63.2988 32.1891 62.4179 33.7002 61.9984 35.3793V52.632C61.9984 54.0592 61.4531 55.2765 60.3624 56.284C59.3556 57.2075 58.0972 57.6692 56.587 57.6692Z" fill="url(#paint4_linear_809_1834)"/>
    <path d="M112.376 9.31541C105.287 10.0754 102.882 22.2992 102.565 28.3161C100.287 29.0761 100.139 22.2992 100.35 18.8158C100.35 17.5491 99.7172 17.0213 99.4007 16.9157C97.9239 16.7046 94.6537 18.1191 93.3879 25.466C92.122 32.813 93.2305 38.8017 93.7355 40.9747C93.9361 41.8379 94.5902 43.6632 95.1622 44.9008C96.8117 48.4699 99.3143 51.8243 103.198 54.6004C108.515 58.4006 116.806 58.0839 120.287 57.4505C123.874 56.6061 130.127 53.2449 132.313 46.6835C134.528 40.0332 133.79 36.5498 133.262 35.9164C132.946 35.0719 131.743 33.383 129.465 33.383C127.186 33.383 126.195 35.4942 125.984 36.5498C125.878 36.7609 125.667 37.8165 125.667 40.3499C125.667 42.8833 123.557 45.4168 122.503 46.3668C120.182 47.6335 114.654 49.2169 111.11 45.4168C107.565 41.6166 109.211 37.4998 110.477 35.9164C111.215 34.8608 113.515 32.6863 116.806 32.4329C120.097 32.1796 123.241 35.0719 124.401 36.5498C124.148 33.763 127.039 31.5885 128.515 30.8495C125.667 27.9994 122.819 26.7327 121.553 26.0994C120.54 25.5927 120.92 23.8826 121.553 23.2493L131.68 11.5322L125.351 17.5491L126.808 16.1639L131.68 11.5322C131.996 10.7932 131.49 9.44209 126.933 9.94877C121.237 10.5821 114.591 21.6659 111.426 23.2493C108.895 24.516 110.16 20.8214 111.11 18.8158C112.059 17.2324 114.085 13.5589 114.591 11.5322C115.097 9.50542 113.325 9.20986 112.376 9.31541Z" fill="url(#paint5_linear_809_1834)"/>
    <path d="M131.68 11.5322C131.996 10.7932 131.49 9.44209 126.933 9.94877C121.237 10.5821 114.591 21.6659 111.426 23.2493C108.895 24.516 110.16 20.8214 111.11 18.8158C112.059 17.2324 114.085 13.5589 114.591 11.5322C115.097 9.50542 113.325 9.20986 112.376 9.31541C105.287 10.0754 102.882 22.2992 102.565 28.3161C100.287 29.0761 100.139 22.2992 100.35 18.8158C100.35 17.5491 99.7172 17.0213 99.4007 16.9157C97.9239 16.7046 94.6537 18.1191 93.3879 25.466C92.122 32.813 93.2305 38.8017 93.7355 40.9747M131.68 11.5322L126.808 16.1639L125.351 17.5491L131.68 11.5322ZM131.68 11.5322L121.553 23.2493C120.92 23.8826 120.54 25.5927 121.553 26.0994C122.819 26.7327 125.667 27.9994 128.515 30.8495C127.039 31.5885 124.148 33.763 124.401 36.5498C123.241 35.0719 120.097 32.1796 116.806 32.4329C113.515 32.6863 111.215 34.8608 110.477 35.9164C109.211 37.4998 107.565 41.6166 111.11 45.4168C114.654 49.2169 120.182 47.6335 122.503 46.3668C123.557 45.4168 125.667 42.8833 125.667 40.3499C125.667 37.8165 125.878 36.7609 125.984 36.5498C126.195 35.4942 127.186 33.383 129.465 33.383C131.743 33.383 132.946 35.0719 133.262 35.9164C133.79 36.5498 134.528 40.0332 132.313 46.6835C130.127 53.2449 123.874 56.6061 120.287 57.4505C116.806 58.0839 108.515 58.4006 103.198 54.6004C99.3143 51.8243 96.8117 48.4699 95.1622 44.9008M93.7355 40.9747C93.9361 41.8379 94.5902 43.6632 95.1622 44.9008M93.7355 40.9747L95.1622 44.9008M156.656 57.6692C153.048 57.6692 149.734 56.8297 146.714 55.1506C143.693 53.4715 141.26 51.1628 139.415 48.2244C137.653 45.202 136.772 41.8019 136.772 38.0239C136.772 34.162 137.653 30.8038 139.415 27.9494C141.26 25.011 143.693 22.7442 146.714 21.1491C149.734 19.47 153.048 18.6304 156.656 18.6304C160.347 18.6304 163.661 19.47 166.597 21.1491C169.618 22.7442 172.009 25.011 173.771 27.9494C175.533 30.8038 176.413 34.162 176.413 38.0239C176.413 41.8019 175.533 45.202 173.771 48.2244C172.009 51.1628 169.618 53.4715 166.597 55.1506C163.661 56.8297 160.347 57.6692 156.656 57.6692ZM156.656 47.4688C159.256 47.4688 161.354 46.5873 162.948 44.8242C164.626 42.9772 165.465 40.7104 165.465 38.0239C165.465 35.2534 164.626 33.0286 162.948 31.3495C161.354 29.6704 159.256 28.8309 156.656 28.8309C154.139 28.8309 151.999 29.6704 150.237 31.3495C148.559 33.0286 147.721 35.2534 147.721 38.0239C147.721 40.7104 148.559 42.9772 150.237 44.8242C151.999 46.5873 154.139 47.4688 156.656 47.4688ZM192.916 57.6692C187.211 57.6692 182.513 56.4939 178.822 54.1431C178.067 53.6394 177.521 53.0517 177.186 52.3801C176.85 51.6245 176.682 50.9109 176.682 50.2393C176.682 48.812 177.144 47.5108 178.067 46.3354C179.073 45.16 180.29 44.5723 181.716 44.5723C182.387 44.5723 183.058 44.7403 183.73 45.0761C185.24 45.7477 186.96 46.3354 188.889 46.8391C190.819 47.2589 192.581 47.4688 194.175 47.4688C197.279 47.4688 198.831 46.7552 198.831 45.3279C198.831 44.4884 198.454 43.7748 197.699 43.1871C196.943 42.5155 195.182 42.0537 192.413 41.8019C191.322 41.7179 189.896 41.55 188.134 41.2981C186.456 41.0463 184.778 40.5845 183.1 39.9129C181.422 39.1573 179.996 38.0659 178.822 36.6387C177.731 35.2114 177.186 33.2805 177.186 30.8458C177.186 27.0679 178.612 24.0875 181.464 21.9047C184.317 19.7218 188.134 18.6304 192.916 18.6304C195.685 18.6304 198.286 18.9243 200.719 19.512C203.236 20.0996 205.123 20.9812 206.382 22.1565C207.556 23.2479 208.144 24.5072 208.144 25.9345C208.144 27.1938 207.682 28.3272 206.759 29.3346C205.837 30.3421 204.662 30.8458 203.236 30.8458C202.481 30.8458 201.768 30.6779 201.096 30.3421C200.09 29.6704 198.789 29.1667 197.195 28.8309C195.685 28.4951 194.133 28.3272 192.539 28.3272C189.351 28.3272 187.757 28.9988 187.757 30.3421C187.757 30.9298 188.05 31.4755 188.638 31.9792C189.309 32.399 190.777 32.7768 193.042 33.1126C194.468 33.2805 196.104 33.5323 197.95 33.8682C199.796 34.12 201.558 34.6237 203.236 35.3793C204.998 36.051 206.466 37.1844 207.64 38.7795C208.815 40.3746 209.402 42.5574 209.402 45.3279C209.402 49.1059 207.892 52.1282 204.872 54.395C201.851 56.5778 197.866 57.6692 192.916 57.6692ZM208.358 23.6677C208.358 21.9886 208.946 20.7293 210.12 19.8897C211.295 19.0502 212.637 18.6304 214.147 18.6304C215.322 18.6304 216.329 18.9662 217.168 19.6379C218.091 20.2256 218.72 21.0651 219.055 22.1565L226.858 41.1722C227.277 42.2636 227.865 42.8093 228.62 42.8093C229.375 42.8093 229.92 42.2636 230.256 41.1722L237.051 22.1565C237.471 20.9812 238.142 20.0996 239.065 19.512C240.072 18.9243 241.12 18.6304 242.211 18.6304C243.637 18.6304 244.938 19.0922 246.112 20.0157C247.371 20.9392 248 22.1565 248 23.6677C248 24.5072 247.832 25.3048 247.497 26.0604L227.865 71.3958C227.277 72.6551 226.522 73.5366 225.599 74.0403C224.76 74.628 223.879 74.9219 222.957 74.9219C221.446 74.9219 220.062 74.3762 218.804 73.2848C217.629 72.2773 217.042 71.06 217.042 69.6327C217.042 68.8772 217.21 68.2055 217.545 67.6178L224.341 55.5284C222.915 55.1086 221.782 54.0592 220.943 52.3801L208.736 25.9345C208.484 25.1789 208.358 24.4233 208.358 23.6677ZM45.0462 53.0098C43.4521 54.2691 41.0191 55.3605 37.7471 56.284C34.4751 57.2075 31.287 57.6692 28.1828 57.6692C22.9811 57.6692 18.3248 56.5359 14.2139 54.2691C10.1029 51.9184 6.87283 48.6861 4.5237 44.5723C2.17457 40.4586 1 35.7991 1 30.5939C1 25.1369 2.13262 20.4355 4.39785 16.4896C6.74698 12.5437 9.97703 9.52137 14.088 7.42251C18.199 5.2397 22.9811 4.14829 28.4345 4.14829C30.6997 4.14829 32.965 4.35818 35.2302 4.77795C37.5793 5.19772 39.7187 5.86936 41.6483 6.79286C42.6551 7.29658 43.3682 7.96822 43.7877 8.80776C44.2911 9.56335 44.5428 10.4029 44.5428 11.3264C44.5428 12.6697 44.0394 13.929 43.0327 15.1043C42.1098 16.1958 40.8513 16.7415 39.2573 16.7415C38.5861 16.7415 37.873 16.6155 37.1179 16.3637C35.6077 15.776 33.9717 15.3142 32.2099 14.9784C30.448 14.5586 28.8959 14.3488 27.5536 14.3488C23.1909 14.3488 19.5414 15.818 16.6049 18.7564C13.7524 21.6948 12.3262 25.6406 12.3262 30.5939C12.3262 35.8831 13.7944 40.0388 16.7308 43.0612C19.7511 46.0835 23.6104 47.5947 28.3086 47.5947C30.2383 47.5947 32.2938 47.2589 34.4751 46.5873C36.6564 45.9156 38.4183 45.0761 39.7607 44.0686C40.6835 43.4809 41.6903 43.1871 42.781 43.1871C44.2072 43.1871 45.3398 43.6908 46.1788 44.6983C47.1017 45.6218 47.5631 46.7971 47.5631 48.2244C47.5631 50.0714 46.7241 51.6665 45.0462 53.0098ZM56.587 57.6692C54.993 57.6692 53.6506 57.2075 52.5599 56.284C51.4693 55.3605 50.9239 54.1851 50.9239 52.7579V5.91133C50.9239 4.56806 51.4273 3.43468 52.4341 2.51118C53.5248 1.50373 54.9091 1 56.587 1C58.1811 1 59.4815 1.50373 60.4883 2.51118C61.495 3.43468 61.9984 4.61004 61.9984 6.03727V22.7862C63.0891 21.5269 64.5573 20.5194 66.403 19.7638C68.2488 19.0082 70.2204 18.6304 72.3178 18.6304C77.0161 18.6304 80.7915 20.0157 83.644 22.7862C86.5804 25.5567 88.0486 29.9643 88.0486 36.009V53.0098C88.0486 54.353 87.5033 55.4864 86.4126 56.4099C85.4058 57.2495 84.1054 57.6692 82.5114 57.6692C80.9173 57.6692 79.5749 57.2075 78.4843 56.284C77.4775 55.3605 76.9741 54.1851 76.9741 52.7579V37.3942C76.9741 34.2879 76.261 32.0631 74.8347 30.7199C73.4924 29.3766 71.8144 28.705 69.8009 28.705C67.7034 28.705 65.9835 29.4186 64.6412 30.8458C63.2988 32.1891 62.4179 33.7003 61.9984 35.3793V52.632C61.9984 54.0592 61.4531 55.2765 60.3624 56.284C59.3556 57.2075 58.0972 57.6692 56.587 57.6692Z" stroke="url(#paint6_linear_809_1834)" stroke-width="0.263406" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</svg>
```